# Cloudwatch: event type syntax for monitoring S3 files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I need to create a cloudwatch event that runs a lambda function everytime my file in S3 gets updated/re-uploaded. What "eventName" should I use? I tried using "ObjectCreated" but it doesn't seem to work. Perhaps the syntax is incorrect.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.s3"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [ "ObjectCreated:*"],
    "requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": [
        "mynewbucket"
      ],
      "key": [
        "file.csv"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudWatch Events (or EventBridge) does not automatically track data events for S3 objects. You need to either use CloudTrail for this, which tracks data events on a particular S3 bucket and emits CloudWatch Events (or EventBridge) events for that: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-dynamic-amazon-s3-event-handling-with-amazon-eventbridge/

Or you can use [S3 Event Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html) with an SNS topic and use a Lambda subscription on the SNS topic.

Comment: I see that we can add event notifications for a bucket in S3. Is it possible to add event notifications for just a particular object in a bucket? For eg file hello.txt in my bucket/folder/hello.txt